# Slow Ubuntu Booting

Tags: 14.04, boot

**Problem**:

It takes too much to start Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 32-bit (7 minutes after the Grub screen).

**Problem description**

1. I turn on the PC
2. 1 minute after the Grub screen appears
3. Once selected Ubuntu as the operative system it starts the process of loading the OS.
4. 7 minutes later, the login screen of Ubuntu appears.
5. Once Ubuntu starts, everything works 100%

**Computer description**

- Laptop ACER Aspire 5542-5770
- CPU: AMD Turion II X2 M500 – 2.2GHz, 1MB L2 Cache
- Video card: ATI Radeon HD 4200 Graphics up to 1919 MB HyperMemory
- RAM: 4 Gb
- Hard drive: 320 Gb (/dev/sdb)
- Ubuntu is not installed in the laptop hard drive, it's installed in a portable hard drive connected through USB.

**External hard drive Toshiba 500 Gb (/dev/sda)**

- /dev/sda1 – ext2 - /boot – 2 Gb
- /dev/sda2 – ext4 - / - 50 Gb
- /dev/sda3 – extended

  - /dev/sda5 – linux-swap – 2 Gb
  - /dev/sda6 – ext4 - /home – 172 Gb
- Free – 240 Gb

Records from boot are useless. All the records start 30 seconds before Ubuntu starts, meaning that they start 6 minutes and 30 seconds after the Grub screen.

**Solutions tested** (It didn't work)

- /etc/default/grub: I tried modifying this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
- I tried using all this parameters: splash – quiet – noapic – nolapic – acpi=noirq

None of this makes a change at all.

**I am also sending all the reports, and it must be taken into account that I turned on the computer at 22:00.**

Logs [on pastebin.org](http://pastebin.com/1jVJxp0u) or on [drive.google.com (original link)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15XOD-B1l85n-1C6Qh10NjQHPx5uUe4m586FKNoyV7jA&authuser=0)

Bootchart Image [on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P2A8.png) or on [drive.google.com (original link)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9p-rpoU17qNX0F1Q25LbU1yQWM&authuser=0)

Edit

**It is not a problem of USB speed**. In another computer it tooks less than one minute to start, so the problem is my Laptop.

Comment: I never tried something like that but I am almost certin that the proble it's the USB.

Comment: As you can see here USB it's much slower than SATA, but after the system boots it stay's on the RAM that's why after loading it gets faster. Here's a [link](http://superuser.com/a/138854) that you can use to compare the speeds.

Comment: cesar.rickinho: It could be that the USB thing is the problem, but, I do remeber of installing Ubuntu once and didn't have all this time problems. The main problem in that install was that I didn't create a /boot partition, so the USB Hard drive only worked in my computer and thats not the point at all. Do you know a way to maybe see what's going on in that seven minutes that  is loading Ubuntu?

Comment: It is not a USB problem. In another computer with USB 2.0 and not better than mine it boots in less than one minute. I need help please, it is not a USB speed problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bootchart (check out https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting ) which will show you all the steps in the boot process and will help you locate where the delays are.

EDIT: apologies for not reading the post fully...saw your bootchart diagram but unfortunately it only shows up only 60s worth of info. You may want to check beyond the 60s to see which process is holding things up.

Comment: I want to check beyond the 60s. How can I do that? I did tested in another computer and it boots in less than one minute.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bios settings. 1 minute for grub alone is a long time. Specifically check for USB legacy settings (which set all USB ports to 1.1 speeds for compatibility). Also check CPU and ram compatibility settings while you're at it.

The biggest key is the same drive boots fast on another machine. That hints at a machine specific problem.